# strange python regex behavior - maybe connected to unicode or sqlalchemy

Tags: python, regex, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to search for a pattern in sqlalchemy results (actually filter by a 'like' or 'op'('regexp')(pattern) which I believe is implanted with regex somewhere) - the string and the search string are both in hebrew, and presumably (maybe I'm wrong-)-unicode
where `r = u'לבן'` and `c = u'לבן, ורוד,    '`
when I do `re.search(r,c)` I get the `SRE.match` object
but when I query the db like:

```
f = session.query(classname)
c = f[0].color
```

and c gives me:

```
'\xd7\x9c\xd7\x91\xd7\x9f,\xd7\x95\xd7\xa8\xd7\x95\xd7\x93,'
```

or `print (c):`

```
לבן,ורוד,
```

practicaly the same but running `re.search(r,c)` gives me no match object.

Since I suspected a unicode issue I tried to transform to unicode with `unicode(c)`
and I get an 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal' which I guess means this is already unicode string - so where's the catch here?
I would prefer using the sqlalchemy `'like'` but I get the same problem there = where I know for sure (as I showed in my example that the data contains the string)

Should I transform the search string,pattern somehow? is this related to unicode? something else?

The db table (which I'm quering) collation is utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 3):

```
c = f[0].color
```

is not returning a Unicode string (or its `repr()` would show a `u'...'` kind of string), but a UTF-8 encoded string.

Try

```
c = f[0].color.decode("utf-8")
```

which results in

```
u'\u05dc\u05d1\u05df,\u05d5\u05e8\u05d5\u05d3,'
```

or

```
u'לבן,ורוד,'
```

if your console can display Hebrew characters.

Comment: sorry folks I already walked in that path and this doesn't work(just rechecked) - I get the unicode object after the decoding, but the re.search still gives me 'none'

Answer (score 2):

`'\xd7\x9c\xd7\x91\xd7\x9f,\xd7\x95\xd7\xa8\xd7\x95\xd7\x93,` is encoded representation of string `u'לבן, ורוד, '`. So in the second example you should write `re.search(r,c.decode('utf-8'))`
You're trying to do almost the same except setting encoding parameter. It makes python try ascii encoding